# java.sql.SQLException: Procedure or function ... expects parameter ..., which was not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

While executing `daoMethod()` I am getting the following exception:

**java.sql.SQLException: Procedure or function 'Get_Books' expects parameter '@totalRowsReturned', which was not supplied.**

Why? I did define `@totalRowsReturned` as OUTPUT. And I do not understand why I am required to supply `@totalRowsReturned` - it is an output parameter, not input.

Dao Class:

```
public class BookDao {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public void daoMethod() {

        Integer programIdLocal = null;

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("bookId", 1);

        MyStoredProcedure storedProcedure = new MyStoredProcedure(dataSource);      

        //Exception!!!!
        Map<String, Object> results = storedProcedure.execute(parameters);

    }

    private class MyStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {

        private static final String SQL = "dbo.Get_Books";

        public MyStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource) {
            setDataSource(dataSource);
            setFunction(true);
            setSql(SQL);

            declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("rs", new BookMapper()));

            declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("totalRowsReturned", Types.INTEGER));

            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("bookId", Types.INTEGER));

            setFunction(true);

            compile();
        }

    }   
}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Books]

    @bookId int,
    @totalRowsReturned int OUTPUT

AS

BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @SelectQuery NVARCHAR(2000)

  DECLARE @first_id int
  DECLARE @totalRows int

  SET @SelectQuery = 'FROM books b WHERE b.book_id >= @bookId'

  Set @SelectQuery = 'SELECT @first_id = b.book_id , @totalRows=Count(*) OVER() ' + @SelectQuery + ' ORDER BY b.book_id'
  Execute sp_Executesql @SelectQuery, N'@first_id int, @bookId int, @totalRows int OUTPUT', @first_id, @bookId, @totalRows=@totalRowsReturned OUTPUT

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a important caveat in [the Javadoc for `StoredProcedure#declareParameter()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html#declareParameter%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter%29) that you must declare the parameters in the order they are declared in the stored procedure, presumably because the same restriction exists for [the underlying `CallableStatement` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html). That means you should be declaring `@bookId` before `@totalRowsReturned`.

Also, I'm not all that knowledgable about JdbcTemplate but, [based on this example](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-StoredProcedure), I don't think you need to declare a result set parameter.

Comment: Thank you - I changed the order and this Exception is gone (I also had to change to `setFunction(false);` - since thie procedure is not a function. The problem is: I am now getting the exception: **java.sql.SQLException: Must declare the scalar variable "@totalRows".** Any ideas why?

Comment: this is not the solution for the problem